# With iOS 9's multitasking, can my app receive dragged content from another app?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, multitasking

I want users to be able to drag a picture or text from an external app onto a “drop zone” in my app in iOS 9 in SplitView.

Is this doable? I don't seem to find any API in the docs to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible right now as far as I can see in the documentation. It's likely this might be something that comes in iOS 10 as Apple tend to build up to new features. e.g. Size Classes > Multitasking > Sharing.